# Отсутствует перевод на странице "Связаться с нами"

Tags: дефект, статус-запланировано, перевод

На странице [Связаться с нами](https://rus.stackexchange.com/contact) отсутствует перевод верхней части.

> [image: Связаться с нами]

В traducir этого текста нет, но на других сайтах текст переведён. Пример: https://es.stackoverflow.com/contact

Comment: Отправил заявку разработчикам.

Answer (score 1):

Отправил просьбу исправить, спасибо!

С наступающими праздниками!